# Infinitesimal generator of Brownian motion with additional jumps

Tags: probability, probability-theory, markov-process

A compound Poisson process is a jump process with two parameters, the rate of the jumps $\lambda$ and the distribution of the jumps $\mu$ ($\mu$ is a probability measure on $\mathbb{R}$). The infinitesimal generator of this process is given by:
$$A_{\lambda,\mu}f(x) = \lambda\int_\mathbb{R} (f(x+z)-f(x))\mu(dz)$$
What happen if I take a brownian motion with generator $\frac{1}{2}f''$ and construct the process with generator $\frac{1}{2}f''+A_{\lambda,\mu}$.
Is this process the sum of a brownian motion with an a independent compound poisson process with parameters $\lambda, \mu$? If the answer is yes, How we can generalize this notion? for example, If we take a general process with generator $L$ and we construct the process with generator $L+A$ is this process the sum of a $L$-process and a independent $A$-process.

I think that total generality it is not true because the $L$-process can have jumps with rate dependent on the state.

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: You aren't adding an independent process, you're coupling the two. So in particular it isn't the same as just adding the processes themselves, unless the processes you're adding are space-homogeneous.

Comment: thanks,
what is your definition of a space-homogeneous markov process?

Comment: The generator doesn't depend explicitly on $x$. For example, Brownian motion is space homogeneous, but a process with generator $f \mapsto xf''$ is not.

Comment: Is there an easy way to check that the generator of the sum of two space homogeneous process is the sum of the generators?

Comment: Write out the three relevant SDEs and observe that the sum of two of them solves the third one.

Comment: @Ian Do you have a reference for the proof?

Comment: @user90803 You write that you would like to construct a process with generator $L+A$. Do you have any assumptions on the domain of $A$ and $L$? In general, the best you can expect is that the generator of the (new) process equals $Lf+Af$ for any function $f$ which is in the domain of $A$ and also in the domain of $L$. Is this what you are looking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The generator of a sum of (time- and space-) homogeneous independent Markov processes is a sum of generators.

Indeed, let $X$ and $Y$ be these processes. Denote by $T_t$ and $S_t$ their Markov semigroups, $A$ and $B$ their generators, $\mathsf E_{x,y}$ the expectation given $X_0=x, Y_0=y$. Then for any $f\in C_b(\mathbb R)$ (bounded continuous), using the independence and homogeneity,
$$
\mathsf E_{x,y}[f(X_t + Y_t)] = \mathsf E_{x,y}[\mathsf E_{x,y}[f(X_t + z)]|_{z=Y_t}]= \mathsf E_{x,y}[\mathsf E_{x+z,y}[f(X_t)]|_{z=Y_t}]
\\ = \mathsf E_y[T_t f(x+z)|_{z=Y_t}] = S_t T_tf (x+y).
$$
Similarly, it equals to $T_t S_t f (x+y)$, in particular, $T_t$ and $S_t$ commute (and so do $A$ and $B$). Now for $f\in C_b^2(\mathbb R)$ (bounded twice continuously differentiable with bounded derivatives), differentiating this equality in $t$ for $t=0$, we get 
$$
\frac{d}{dt}\mathsf E_{x,y}[f(X_t + Y_t)]|_{t=0} = (A+B)f(x+y),
$$
which means that $A+B$ is the generator of $X+Y$.

There is another way to look at this. A time- and space-homogeneous process is a Lévy process, which can be written as a sum 
$$
at + b W_t + Z_t,
$$
where $W_t$ is a standard Wiener process, and $Z_t$ is a pure jump process. When you add two independent things of such kind, you arrive to
$$
(a_1+a_2)t + \sqrt{b_1^2 + b_2^2}\, W_t + (Z_t^1 + Z_t^2).
$$
The process $Z_t = Z_t^1 + Z_t^2$ is again a pure jump process, and the jump intensities at a given level just add up. If you translate these things to generator, everything will add up to; for instance, the diffusion part is 
$\left(\sqrt{b_1^2 + b_2^2}\right)^2 \frac{d^2}{dx^2} = (b_1^2 + b_2^2)\frac{d^2}{dx^2}$.